# Committing changes to a new branch and leaving the current branch clean?

Tags: git

I have a bunch of changes in a branch that I didn't commit yet. They ended up getting more experimental then I thought they would and I would like to keep the current branch how it is and put them in a new branch. How can i do this?

Comment: The duplicate should take care of you. The important thing to note here is that the first sentence of your question has led you astray. Branches point to commits, so anything uncommitted is not in a branch. Your changes are only in the work tree, and you can freely switch to another branch at the same commit (so that Git doesn't need to check out different versions of files in the work tree) without affecting those changes.

Comment: Thanks jefromi, makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -b new_branch
git add -A
git commit
```